# Count pwm pulses on pic

Tags: pic, pwm, timer, counter, c18

I'm working on PIC18F8722 to generate PWM for 50% duty cycle. I have obtained the PWM and now I need to count the PWM pulse. As per my knowledge we can use timers to generate and count those pulses with a counter. I 'm not understanding how exactly to do it. Any advice is appreciable.

Thanks!

Comment: It's unusual to count pulses in PWM. Usually one is trying to provide an equivalent DC level for a time. Why do you need to count the actual pulses? You should already know the frequency because your configuration has set it.

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? How big is the pulse count likely to be? (see my answer to understand why this is important) Pulse counts that fit into a one byte variable are simpler to handle than counts which take more than one byte.

Comment: I need to count the pulses and when it reaches the particular value set then need to stop the PWM.

Comment: In PIC18FXX8 series, Timer0 can act as a timer as well as a counter depending on how you configure the Timer0 control register i.e. T0CON. You can configure it as a 8 bit counter or a 16 bit counter depending on the number of pulses you need to count. So, basically,your PWM pulses are given as input to pin T0CKI/RA4 in PIC18F458, and the timer0 increments on either the rising edge or falling edge of the input pulses. For more details just checkout Page 109,section 11.0 here http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41159d.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The timer being used to generate the PWM signal has an interrupt service routine (ISR). It is either triggered every time the output pin changes (Interrupt on match), or the timer is reloaded (Interrupt-on-overflow).

That interrupt service routine can increment a variable to count one more pulse every time it is called.

AFAICT, all of the PIC18F8722 timers support, at least, one of those two types of ISR.

There is no need for another hardware counter.

The pulse count will be stored in a 'global' variable and so can be read by code outside the ISR. If you are using C to program the PIC18F8722, then the pulse count variable will be defined as 'volatile'.

Ideally, the count will fit in one byte, you will only need to count up to 255. However, if the pulse count variable needs to be bigger than a byte, you'll need to be slightly careful how the code outside the ISR uses it.

A variable bigger than one byte will be read in several instructions, so it is possible for the interrupt to happen in the middle of the main code accessing its value. This can result in the main code occasionally getting confused about the actual value of the pulse count.

(Please add a bit more information to your question, so that we can understand if you need help with solving this kind of problem. If it is not an issue, it seems too much complexity to add to an answer.)